# Solving complex quadratic with $x x^{*}$ and not $ |x|^{2}$

Tags: complex-numbers

I’m trying to solve a fairly simple AC circuit analytically for $V_2$. After a little bit of work, I end up with the following expression:

$$V_2\cdot V_2 − V_1\cdot V_2^* + S\cdot Z = 0$$
or alternatively

$$x^* x + B x^* + C = 0$$

where $x, B, C$ (and $V_1, V_2, S, Z$) are complex.  Is there a quadratic formula for this form?  What is it and does it come from completing the square?  Often $x x^{*}$ is taken as $|x|^{2}$, but is that general and does the solution for $x$ specify a distinct angle?

Comment: $x^*x=(x^*x)^*=\|x\|^2$

Comment: Unfortunately it is trickier than the usual quadratic formula. You can easily have infinite solutions. Consider for example $(x-1)(x^\star-1)=1$, which is the equation of a circle.